# ucrtbased.dll vs ucrtbase.dll

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

C Runtime for Windows10 is shipped in ucrtbase.dll. But they also have ucrtbased, which is "debug version". What exactly does it contain? Why do I need debug version of dll if I have .pdb (public symbols) for it?

Comment: It contains [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Just to give what I know.

1. The ucrtbase.dll is compiled using maximum optimisation, and ucrtbased.dll is not.
2. The ucrtbased.dll carries more/different information than the ucrtbase.dll. They are helping in setting up debug environment.
   These information can be seen if you try to run "dumpbin" on it.
   Fox example, if you compare results from `dumpbin /exports ucrtbased.dll` and `dumpbin /exports ucrtbase.dll`. If you do a diff on the output:
   you will find some of the functions exported are different, like this:

   `_wfullpath`
   `+_wfullpath_dbg`
   `_wgetcwd`
   `+_wgetcwd_dbg`

   Also some can only seen in ucrtbased.dll, like this:

   `_utime32`
   `_utime64`
   `+_VCrtDbgReportA`
   `+_VCrtDbgReportW`

   For more information, you may just try dumpbin in different ways to see what you can find.